# Get list inside the annotate in django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, orm

I have 3 tables:-

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
       id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       name = models.CharField()
       .....
       #some more field
       .....

class ProfileTestMapping(models.Model):
         id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
         test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
         .....
         #some more field
         ....

class Test(models.Model):
         id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         name = models.CharField()
        .....
         #some more field
         ....
```

1 profile has many tests. So I want to get the data like this:-

```
This is a raw array I am writing for the example purpose. 
profileList = [

    {
        profileName: 'any-name',
        ......
        otherProfileDetails
        .......
        testList: [
         {
            name: testName,
            id: 463743
         },
         {
            name: testName2,
            id: 463743
         }
        ]
     }
]
```

I am getting the `count` of test mapped with the profile using `annotate` but not getting the details of the test which are mapped with the profile.

**UPDATED:-**
Current Query I am getting the number of the count but not List of mapped test data:-

```
Profile.objects.filter(isDisable=0).value('id', 'name').annotate(
  testCount = Count('profiletestmapping__test_id')
  testList = //Unable to get list of related data
)
```

Comment: Post the query that you have used to generate the output you have mentioned.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Question updated.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI you don't need to annotate the test objects since they're already in the db. All you need do is join them while fetching which prefetch_related does

Comment: @Ken4scholars Okay I am trying.

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI did it work? don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if it did

Answer (score 0):

You can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to join all the tests while selecting a profile.

```
Profile.objects.prefetch_related(
'ProfileTestMapping_set__test'
).all()
```

Comment: @GAJESHPANIGRAHI try what I suggested and show the result. Of course you can annotate it with count if you like